# Можно ли произносить время 11:00 как "один один ноль ноль"?

Tags: числительные

Я много раз слышал, как ведущий радиостанции "Европа плюс" произносит время 11:00 по Москве как "в Москве один один ноль ноль".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да ни за что!

Прикалывается так ведущий радиостанции "Европа плюс". Мог бы и сказануть "одиннадцать по нулям" (к примеру) или "обнулённые двадцать три".

Мы бы поняли. То есть информация донесена - коммуникация осуществилась.